# Programmatically Disable Windows Autoplay

Tags: wmi, windows-xp, autoplay

I am trying to disable Autoplay for all devices in Windows XP programmatically. I know how to do it by running gpedit.msc, then navigating to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Turn off Autoplay. I just need a way to do it programmatically now. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I need this because I'm trying to write a script or executable of some sort that my company can use to automatically harden security on new PCs. I am thinking about trying to do it in Python, but I'm open to other suggestions as well.